# Parts not working when using multiple languages with polyglossia

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia, parts

I'm working on a `book` document with `xelatex`.
The document is divided into `parts`, and I have the occasional need to switch between two languages.

I've found that when my document contains more than one language, the `part` number is not displayed anymore:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
  \selectlanguage{french}
  \selectlanguage{english}

  \part{My Part}
\end{document}
```

Will result in:

[image: Not displaying part number]

If I use just one language, I'm not having any problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
  % \selectlanguage{french}
  \selectlanguage{english}

  \part{My Part}
\end{document}
```

[image: Displaying part number]

Chapters and sections work good in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `french` language redefines `\thepart` to issue nothing, because it wants “Première partie”. So if you switch to French, the command is redefined, but switching to English doesn't define it back.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@thepart\thepart
\appto\noextras@french{\let\thepart\latex@thepart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
\selectlanguage{english}

\part{My Part}

\end{document}
```

Save the original `\thepart` command and restore it when the language switches from French to another one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes a lot of sense, and your solution is working great!

Comment: From polyglossia v. 1.51, you can set the frenchpart option to false when loading the package.